# Access: Preventing duplicates with parameters

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have the following tables:

room and 
course

when entering entries into the course table I want the specific room number to be unavailable for the duration of the course. Course duration can be 1, 3 or 5 days.

I've made it so that the same room can't be re-used on the start date of that course but how could I, for example, make the room, R001, unavailable for say 3 days? I was thinking of adding an finish date and just use >= startDATE AND <= finDate

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Came up with this but not working

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UnavailableRoomIndex
ON CurrentCourse(RoomNo, CourseStartDate)
WHERE CourseStartDate <= dateadd(d, CourseStartDate, CourseDuration);
```

Comment: To the `course` table add a `duration` column that contains the days (or hours perhaps) the course runs for, then use `< dateadd(days, startDate, duration)` (syntax depends on the db your using)

Comment: @AlexK. Why duration Vs end_date/time? Just out of interest